# check box value taking no default

Tags: php

There is Three issue one when i am updating values ill get all the values in field but it not update check box value it giving No value always at update time.

Second if i am not choosing any file than its not taking file which is get by id i have choose file by Default.

Three i wants current date in date picker current date is getting but when i am click on update its take current value only please give me solution as early as possible thank u.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">


   <head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>

<?php
include('header1.php');

?>
<!-- Javascript -->

      </head>
      <body >


        <?php
          include('sidenav.php');
          ?>

     <div id="page-wrapper" >
     <div id="page-inner">
     <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-12">



    <?php
     if(isset($_GET['id']))
     {
        $id = $_GET['id'];
     echo"<h2>Update Product</h2>";
     }
     else
     {
        echo"<h2>Add Product</h2>";
     }   
    ?>    

                </div>
                </div>
                 <!-- /. ROW  -->
                 <hr />
                 <div class="row"> 

                      <?php 

                       include('config.php');
                        if(isset($_GET['id']))
                        {
                            $id = $_GET['id'];
                            if(isset($_POST['submit']))
                            {


                                echo "working"; 
                                    $fileName=$_FILES["filepdf"]["name"];
                                    $fileSize=$_FILES["filepdf"]["size"]/2024;
                                    $fileType=$_FILES["filepdf"]["type"];   
                                    $fileTmpName=$_FILES["filepdf"]["tmp_name"]; 

                                    if($fileType=="application/pdf")
                                    {
                                        if($fileSize<=200)
                                    { 
                                        $random=rand(1111,9999);
                                        $newFileName=$random.$fileName;
                                        $uploadPath="testUpload/".$newFileName;
                                        if(move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName,$uploadPath))
                                    {
                                        echo "Successful<BR>"; 
                                        echo "File Name :".$newFileName."<BR>"; 
                                        echo "File Size :".$fileSize." kb"."<BR>"; 
                                        echo "File Type :".$fileType."<BR>"; 
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        echo "Maximum upload file size limit is 200 kb";
                                    }
                                }
                                    else
                                    {
                                            return false;
                                            echo "You can only upload a pdf doc file.";
                                    }  

                                }   



                                $cat=$_POST['catnm'];
                                $prodnm=$_POST['prodnm'];
                                $prod_dtl=$_POST['prod_dtl'];

                                 $updates = $_POST['downld'] ? 'Yes' : 'No';
                                //$downld=$_POST['downld'];
                                $date=$_POST['date'];
                                $query3=mysql_query("update addproduct set catnm='$cat', prodnm='$prodnm',prod_dtl='$prod_dtl'
                                ,pdf='$uploadPath',downld='$updates',date='$date' where id='$id'");
                                    if($query3)
                                    {
                                        header('location:addProduct.php');
                                    }
                             }
                                $query1=mysql_query("select * from addproduct where id='$id'");
                                $query4=mysql_fetch_array($query1);
                                //echo "<pre>";
                                //print_r($query4);
                            }

                            else
                            {
                            if(isset($_POST['submit']))
                            {

                                    echo"Upload Only PDf File"; 
                                    $fileName=$_FILES["filepdf"]["name"];
                                    $fileSize=$_FILES["filepdf"]["size"]/2024;
                                    $fileType=$_FILES["filepdf"]["type"];   
                                    $fileTmpName=$_FILES["filepdf"]["tmp_name"];  

                            if($fileType=="application/pdf")
                            {
                                if($fileSize<=200){

                            //New file name
                                    $random=rand(1111,9999);
                                    $newFileName=$random.$fileName;

                            //File upload path
                                    $uploadPath="testUpload/".$newFileName;

                            //function for upload file

                                    if(move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName,$uploadPath))
                                    {
                                        echo "Successful<BR>"; 
                                        echo "File Name :".$newFileName."<BR>"; 
                                        echo "File Size :".$fileSize." kb"."<BR>"; 
                                        echo "File Type :".$fileType."<BR>"; 
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        echo "Maximum upload file size limit is 200 kb";
                                    }
                                }
                                    else
                                    {
                                            return false;
                                            echo "You can only upload a pdf file.";
                                    }  


                                        echo "here downld";
                                        $updates = isset($_POST['updates']) ? 'Yes' : 'No';

                                        $catnm=$_POST['catnm'];
                                        $prodnm=$_POST['prodnm'];
                                        $prod_dtl=$_POST['prod_dtl'];

                                        //$updates=$_POST['downld'];
                                        $date=$_POST['date'];

                                        $query=("insert into addproduct(catnm,prodnm,prod_dtl,pdf,downld,date)
                                        values('$catnm','$prodnm','$prod_dtl','$uploadPath','$updates','$date')");
                                        $result = mysql_query($query,$conn);

                                        if($result)
                                        {
                                            header('location:addProduct.php');
                                        }
                                    }

                            }
                            }


                      ?>

           <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">      
                    <div class="panel-body">            
           <form  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"  name="myform" >
                    <br/>

                    <label>Select Category:</label>      
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <?php

                            include('config.php');
                            $query1=mysql_query("select catnm from addcategory");
                            ?>
                            <select class=form-control m-b-10 name=catnm id=catnm >
                            <?php
                             echo"<option>---Select---</option required>";
                            while($query=mysql_fetch_array($query1))
                            {

                                $selectedCat = '';
                                if($query[catnm] == $query4['catnm'])
                                {
                                    $selectedCat = "selected";
                                }

                                 echo "<option value='$query[catnm]' $selectedCat >$query[catnm]</option>"; 
                            }

                        ?>                                    
                        </select>



                <br/>                 
               <div class="form-group">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="prodnm" placeholder="Product Name" name="prodnm" required value="<?php if(isset($query4['prodnm'])){
echo $query4['prodnm'];}?>"/>
               </div>

             <div class="form-group">       
<textarea class="form-control" id="catdtl" name="prod_dtl" placeholder="Product Detail" "rows="10" cols="62" required><?php if(isset($query4['prod_dtl'])){echo $query4['prod_dtl'];} ?></textarea>
            </div>        

            <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputFile">PDF File</label>
            <input type="file" id="exampleInputFile" accept="application/pdf" name="filepdf" >  
            file : <?php if(isset($query4['pdf'])){
            echo $query4['pdf'];} ?>                        
            </div>

            <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
            <input id="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="updates" 
            <?php  if(isset($query4['downld'])) { if($query4['downld'] == 'Yes') echo "checked='checked'"; echo $query4['downld'];} 
            ?> /> Is Downloadable <br />
            </label>
            </div>





     <input type="text" placeholder="Date of Upload" name="date" value="<?php 

    if(isset($query4['date'])){echo $query4['date'];}?>"id="datepicker-7">
                 <div style="padding-top:20px;padding-bottom:40px;width:650px;">


    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="button" value="<?php 

    if(isset($_GET['id'])){$id = $_GET['id'];echo"Update";}else{echo"Submit";}?>"/>


 <input type="button" value="cancel" onclick="window.location='index.php'"/>                         



             <hr/>

             </form>



     </div>
                     <!-- /. ROW  -->
        </div>
                 <!-- /. PAGE INNER  -->
                </div>
             <!-- /. PAGE WRAPPER  -->
            </div>











</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In this line `<input id="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="updates" 
            <?php  if(isset($query4['downld'])) { if($query4['downld'] == 'Yes') echo "checked='checked'"; echo $query4['downld'];} 
            ?> /> Is Downloadable` Where is your `value` attribute ?

Comment: its taking values which had placed in php tag insert ..

Answer (score 0):

your checkbox not have value
try this

```
 <input id="checkbox" value='Yes' type="checkbox" name="updates" 
        <?php  if(isset($query4['downld'])) { if($query4['downld'] == 'Yes') echo "checked='checked'"; echo $query4['downld'];} 
        ?> />
```

Comment: i have solve two now i want to solve file which i had to selected manually at update time

Comment: when i am updating form file take null value its choose manually . I don't want to choose file manually i am getting value of file from database than also ...what to do..?? Any Solution ..

Comment: you siad in update mode, wheh $query4['pdf'] in null. choose manualy??? what choice?